# работа rsync с sftp

Tags: linux, файлы, ssh, sftp, rsync

Есть задача, надо сделать, чтобы rsync работал поверх sftp. Когда я настраиваю rsync без sftp, то все работает - ведь rsync изначально работает по ssh. Но при настройке sftp падает доступ по ssh.
При подключении rsync (при наличии sftp) будет такая ошибка: this service allows sftp connections only. В настройках sftp я закомментировал forcecommand...., после этого подключение по ssh вроде идет, пишет про last login, а потом пишет /bin/bash no such file or directory, connetion to xxx closed. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему. Не надо предлагать альтернативу в виде lftp и тп. Спасибо.

Comment: `rsync` не может работать поверх sftp — только поверх ssh... за остальным — конфиги в студию...

Comment: Проблема XY из палаты мер и весов. Нужно запускать RSYNC через ssh, иначе смысла в нем не будет никакого абсолютно.